# iOS : Firebase Send/Save Data in chunks

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have trying to save data in firebase like this

```
class FirebaseManager {

    static let shared = FirebaseManager()

    private let tableRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "XYZDemo")

    func add(item: HealthData) {
        self.tableRef.childByAutoId().setValue(item.dictionary)
    }
}
```

This code save data one bye one.

How can i add more than one data at a time i.e save 5 values at once?

Comment: You can use [updateChildValues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Answer (score 0):

To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the [updateChildValues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method.

Basicly you create an array with the updates/writes you want to perform and write that array to Firebase. Here is an example showing 1 post being written to two different locations:

```
//Create the new key
let key = self.tableRef.childByAutoId().key
//Post data that is going to be written
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
//Create the array with (two) updates
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
//Write the array to the database
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

A couple things to keep in mind when you are dong this:

- It's all or nothing, either all writes fail or all writes succeed. If even 1 of the writes in the array fails then all writes will fail.
- Make sure you use the correct reference for each write because it will override all the data at that location.